# Using python socket via VPN

Tags: python, sockets, vpn

I am using python to send messages to a specific port of a specific ethernet switch via socket.sendto(message,(SWITCH_IP,SWITCH_PORT)). It works perfectly fine when i am connected directly to the same net as the switch, but when i try it remotely via VPN it just doesnt work.
Here is the code im currently using:

```
message = "Hello, Server!"

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("SWITCH_IP",SWITCH_PORT))
def send_message_read_answer(messag):
    connection.sendto(messag,("SWITCH_IP",SWITCH_PORT))
    print("message sent")
    print(connection.recv(2048))


send_message_read_answer(message)
```

To which i get no response.

I also tried creating a proxy via pysocks:

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "PROXY_IP", PROXY_PORT, True)
s = socks.socksocket()
s.connect(('SWITCH_IP', SWITCH_PORT))
s.sendall(message)
print(s.recv(2048))
```

But i get the error

```
socks.ProxyConnectionError: Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy PROXY_IP:PROXY_PORT: 
[Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Is there any alternative?

Comment: This is nothing about code. You have to setup your network / VPN properly.

Comment: Check the switch to see if those connection attempts and/or pings from outside are even making it to the switch.  It could be a firewall issue--work with your ISP/IT team.   Or the switch might need a default or other route added, or other config change--check with the switch's vendor's docs/Support.

Comment: It was just a improper VPN issue after all, nothing about code really. (im kinda new to stackoverflow, should i post this as an answer?)

Comment: Hi, can you post as an answer?